# Use transform to calculate a value from two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply a small function that uses two parameters on one data frame using the transform function.

Consider this rather useless example function:

```py
import pandas as pd

def example_function(x, y):
    if y=="hi":
        res = x*3
    else:
        res = x
    return res
```

Depending on the value in y ("hi" or something else) the value x will bu multiplied by 3 or returned unaltered.

Given this example Dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([("A",[1,2,3,4]), ("B",["hi", "ho", "ho", "hi"])]))
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   hi  3
1   2   ho  2
2   3   ho  3
3   4   hi  12
```

I assumed that passing two columns should work:

```
df["combined"] = df[["A", "B"]].transform(example_function)
```

but I'm getting an error (Missing 1 required positional argument). Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, because `transform` processing each column separately, so cannot filtering between columns (`Series`).

Solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) working like you need:

```
df["combined"] = df.apply(lambda x: example_function(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
print (df)
   A   B  combined
0  1  hi         3
1  2  ho         2
2  3  ho         3
3  4  hi        12
```

You can check it with this function:

```
def function(x):
    print (x)
    return x

df[["A", "B"]].transform(function)
```